# Joining two tables columns bottom by bottom, not in row

Tags: c#, join

I need to Join 2 tables.

At first the columns of first table and rows.

At bottom line second table columns and rows.

Comment: I don't even understand the description of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try merging the two tables 
Suppose table 1 is dt1, dt2 is second table

then

```
dt1.Merger(dt2)
```

Will merge dt2 in dt1.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need something like the `UNION` statement? Example

```
SELECT ID, Test1, Test2 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID, Test1, Test2 FROM Table2
```

Please note that both `SELECTS` must select the same number of columns with the same column names! It is possible to rename the columns:

```
SELECT ID, Test1, Test2 FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT Identifier as ID, TestColumn1 as Test2, Foo as Test2 FROM Table2
```

This would be if your question includes SQL queries, too (which is hard to tell from the little you're providing in your question).

In C# you can loop over the second table and add rows containing the second table's values in the first table. It is important to note, too, that the number of columns in the second table can not be larger than the number of columns in the first table.

For example:

```
foreach (DataRow r in table2.Rows)
{
    table1.Rows.Add(r[0], r[1], ...);
}
```